# unable to upgrade pop_os from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: dist-upgrade

recently tried to upgrade from pop_os 19.04 to 19.10. 
I tried both using GUI and using the terminal with

`sudo pop-upgrade release upgrade systemd`

both gave me the following message

```
failed to update package lists for the current release: command failed with exit status: exit code: 100
pop-upgrade: dbus client error: calling ReleaseUpgradeFinalize method failed
```

this [comment](https://github.com/pop-os/upgrade/issues/47#issuecomment-578290492) suggested

> The problem is that Disco is not yet available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/, and instead is at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.

I'm pretty clueless about how to manage repositories.

should I just replace  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ with http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  in /etc/apt/sources.list?

any other ideas?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` before running `pop-upgrade release upgrade systemd` as described [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/upgrade-pop/#advanced-install-terminal)?

Comment: You may also wish to contact Pop!_OS Support at http://pop.system76.com/docs , http://reddit.com/r/pop_os , and/or chat.pop-os.org, for a more timely response.

Comment: thanks @Freddy, yes i tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem upgrading from 19.10 to 20.4, what I ended up doing was to upgrade ubuntu first using

`sudo apt install update-manager-core`

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

once ubuntu successfully upgraded to 20.04 (gonna take a while), follow pop os upgrade commands one more time:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

`pop-upgrade release upgrade systemd`